# Async function inside of for loop (Parse Query)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm trying to get all the posts from Parse.com and check if each one is liked by the current user. From what I understand, the inner query can't be done inside the for loop because its an async function.  I don't understand how to format it in a way that allows me to check for each post.  I tried $q.defer() but it didn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
var imageGallery = Parse.Object.extend("Gallery");
var query = new Parse.Query(imageGallery);

query.include("user");
query.near("location", $rootScope.currentLocation);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < results.length; i++) {
      var object = results[i];

      var galleryLike = Parse.Object.extend("GalleryLike");
      var likeQuery = new Parse.Query(galleryLike);

      likeQuery.include('gallery');
      likeQuery.include('user');
      likeQuery.equalTo('gallery', object);
      likeQuery.equalTo('user', Parse.User.current());
      likeQuery.find({
        success: function(res) {
          if (res.length == 0) {
            var like = "false";
          } else {
            var like = "true";
          }
        },
        error: function(error) {

        }
      });

      var distance = object.get('location').kilometersTo($rootScope.currentLocation);

      self.images.push({
        object: object,
        locationName: object.get('locationName'),
        caption: object.get('caption'),
        img: object.get('img').url(),
        username: object.get('user').get('username'),
        userprofpic: object.get('user').get('profpic').url(),
        distance: distance,
        isLiked: like
      });
    }
    $scope.$apply();
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  },
  error: function(error) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: wrap the body of *for loop* in self invoked function and paste the *i as parameter*, should help

Comment: Doing this gives back the results of the query in a random order, rather than by proximity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function which gets only one post, say `getPost()` and it returns a promise.
Then you can use `$q.all()` like following:

```
var promises = [];    
for (var i < results.length; i++) {
    promises.push(getPost(i));
}
$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(results){
        // results[i] is relevant to post #i
    });
```

Comment: I got the liking feature to work using this method but it the results started showing in a random order (everytime the screen was refreshed) rather than by proximity. How would I go about keeping them sorted by proximity as they initially were?

Comment: I think it's because items in results are randomly placed every time you refresh. Please check that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!